How to memoize React elements rendered recursively when updating state object
I'm rendering elements that reflects the structure of an object, so each value is an input, each key is a label and the render function is recursive. When changing the value of an input I update the object with the new value and re-render. The problem is that each re-render is rendering all the elements and it is noticeable in the UI (in delay). I want to memoize the elements so it re-render only the changed input but I am having trouble doing so since I am using a spread operator in order to force the re-render after updating the object.
Let's take an object for example:
{
  "id": "12345",
  "details": {
    "name": "jake",
  },
  "attachments": [
    {"file": "spodjgposg.file"},
    {"file": "sdgidfhoew.file"},
  ],
}

And the component to render the elements base on the object:
// all imports

const MemoObjectRendererInput = React.memo(ObjectRendererInput);

type Data = Record<any, any>;

type Entry = string | boolean | unknown[] | Data;

type Props = {
  onDataChange: (data: Data) => void;
  data: Data;
};

export const ObjectRenderer: FC<Props> = props => {
  const {data, onDataChange} = props;

  const onValueChange = (value: string, path: string) => {
    const _data = {...data};
    updateByPath(_data, path, value); // the function to update the object
    onDataChange(_data);
  };

  const render = (entry: Entry, label = '', level = -1, parent = 'root') => {
    if (typeof entry === 'string' || typeof entry === 'boolean') {
      const path = parent.replace('root.', '');
      return (
        <MemoObjectRendererInput
          onValueChange={v => onValueChange(v, path)}
          label={label}
          value={entry}
        />
      );
    }

    if (Array.isArray(entry)) {
      return (
        <div>
          <ObjectRendererLabel />
          {entry.map((item, index) => {
            return render(item, index.toString(), level + 1);
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }

    if (typeof entry === 'object') {
      return (
        <div>
          <ObjectRendererLabel />
          {isExpanded && Object.entries(entry).map(([key, value]) => {
            return render(value, key, level + 1, [parent, key].join('.'));
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {render(data)}
    </div>
  );
};

This is the updateByPath function:
const updateByPath = (object: Record<any, any>, path: string, value: string | boolean) => {
  const _path = path.split('.');

  while (_path.length > 1) {
    const key = _path.shift();
    if (key) object = object[key];
  }

  const key = _path.shift();
  if (key) object[key] = value;
};

I tried memoize ObjectRendererInput also tried to use useCallback on the render function but when changing a value on an input all the elements are re-rendered.
How can I solve this? What is the best implementation to achieve this?

React itself effectively memoizes the rendering of components when passed the same props. Try refactoring your code away from a single function that recursively renders everything, and instead have one or two components that can iteratively render your structure (from some root node).
Then use a library like Immer or Mutative to control your data changes (makes it easier to avoid re-rendering everything on each change). I will try find some time to write a full answer.

@Sly_cardinal thanks i'll really appreciate a full answer :)

To optimize the rendering in your ObjectRenderer component and avoid re-rendering all elements when only one input value changes, you can memoize the individual elements using React's React.memo or useMemo. However, you'll need to adjust your approach slightly to achieve this. Here's an updated version of your component:
const MemoObjectRendererInput = React.memo(ObjectRendererInput);

type Data = Record<any, any>;

type Entry = string | boolean | unknown[] | Data;

type Props = {
  onDataChange: (data: Data) => void;
  data: Data;
};

export const ObjectRenderer: FC<Props> = props => {
  const { data, onDataChange } = props;

  const onValueChange = (value: string, path: string) => {
    const newData = { ...data };
    updateByPath(newData, path, value);
    onDataChange(newData);
  };

  const renderEntry = useCallback(
    (entry: Entry, label = '', path = 'root') => {
      if (typeof entry === 'string' || typeof entry === 'boolean') {
        return (
          <MemoObjectRendererInput
            key={path}
            onValueChange={v => onValueChange(v, path)}
            label={label}
            value={entry}
          />
        );
      }

      if (Array.isArray(entry)) {
        return entry.map((item, index) =>
          renderEntry(item, index.toString(), `${path}.${index}`)
        );
      }

      if (typeof entry === 'object') {
        return Object.entries(entry).map(([key, value]) =>
          renderEntry(value, key, `${path}.${key}`)
        );
      }

      return null;
    },
    [data, onDataChange]
  );

  return <div>{renderEntry(data)}</div>;
};

In this updated version, renderEntry is memoized using useCallback to prevent unnecessary re-renders of its children. Each ObjectRendererInput component is given a unique key based on its path in the object, ensuring that only the changed input is re-rendered when its value changes.
Please note that the key prop must be unique among siblings, so make sure the paths you use for the key are unique for each input.

this GPT answer isn't working. only change is useCallback? like i wrote, i tried this already.
